# get post count for related author

Tags: custom-post-types, author

I'm trying to use the code below to obtain the number of custom posts the author of a post has published.

```
function count_user_posts_by_type( $userid, $post_type = 'artistblog' ) {
global $wpdb;

$where = get_posts_by_author_sql( $post_type, true, $userid );

$count = $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $wpdb->posts $where" );

return apply_filters( 'get_usernumposts', $count, $userid );
```

For example I'm outputting a loop of custom post types. Next to each post title I'm displaying the author of the post using a similar get_related_author function. I also want to display the number of posts this author has published. I assume I just need to replace $userid with the_author_meta() somehow but haven't managed to get it working.

Am I even approaching this in the right way?

Thanks
D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to read [query_posts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) link to do this. Here you can see 'author' - Order by author.

Simply you can do: `SELECT count(ID) FROM wp_posts groupby author;`

Comment: Thanks Manish. Sorry for the delay in the reply. Your answer helped though.